# AddApiAuthorization no implicit reference conversion ASP Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Trying to implement Identity in ASP.NET Core 3.1. Having some problems getting my head around this.

This is my setup

1. I have separate Projects

   - WebPortal
   - Portal.ApplicationCore
   - Portal.Infrastructure
   - Portal.Domain
2. In Portal.Domain I inherit Identity models

   ```
    public class AppRole : IdentityRole<int>
    {
          [Required]
          public int OrganizationID { get; set; }

          [Required(ErrorMessage = "Display name is Required.")]
          [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Please enter Display name less than 100 characters.")]
          public string DisplayName { get; set; }

          [ForeignKey("OrganizationID")]
          public Organization Organization { get; set; }
     }

     public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int>
     {
          [Required]
          public int OrganizationID { get; set; }

          [ForeignKey("OrganizationID")]
          public Organization Organization { get; set; }
     }
   ```
3. In Portal.Infrastructure I implemented DBContext

   ```
     public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, int>
     {
            private IDbContextTransaction _transaction;
            public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
             : base(options)
            {
            }

            public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }


       }
   ```

Finally in my Startup.cs pop-up error -

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0311  The type 'Portal.Infrastructure.DAL.DatabaseContext.ApplicationDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'IdentityServerBuilderConfigurationExtensions.AddApiAuthorization(IIdentityServerBuilder)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Portal.Infrastructure.DAL.DatabaseContext.ApplicationDbContext' to 'IdentityServer4.EntityFramework.Interfaces.IPersistedGrantDbContext'.

[image: AddApiAuthorization Error]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I solved my problem. I'll post it here and it may help for someone.

1. I create custom **ApiAuthorizationDbContext**

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Database abstraction for a combined <see cref="DbContext"/> using ASP.NET 
   ///Identity and Identity Server.
   /// </summary>
   /// <typeparam name="TUser"></typeparam>
   /// <typeparam name="TRole"></typeparam>
   /// <typeparam name="TKey">Key of the IdentityUser entity</typeparam>
   public class KeyApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey> : 
   IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey>, IPersistedGrantDbContext
   where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey>
   where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey>
   where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
   {
       private readonly IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> _operationalStoreOptions;

       /// <summary>
       /// Initializes a new instance of <see cref="ApiAuthorizationDbContext{TUser, 
       ///TRole, TKey}"/>.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="options">The <see cref="DbContextOptions"/>.</param>
       /// <param name="operationalStoreOptions">The <see 
       ///cref="IOptions{OperationalStoreOptions}"/>.</param>
       public KeyApiAuthorizationDbContext(
       DbContextOptions options,
       IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions)
       : base(options)
       {
           _operationalStoreOptions = operationalStoreOptions;
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{PersistedGrant}"/>.
       /// </summary>
       public DbSet<PersistedGrant> PersistedGrants { get; set; }

       /// <summary>
       /// Gets or sets the <see cref="DbSet{DeviceFlowCodes}"/>.
       /// </summary>
       public DbSet<DeviceFlowCodes> DeviceFlowCodes { get; set; }

       Task<int> IPersistedGrantDbContext.SaveChangesAsync() => 
               base.SaveChangesAsync();

       /// <inheritdoc />
       protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(builder);
           builder.ConfigurePersistedGrantContext(_operationalStoreOptions.Value);
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Database abstraction for a combined <see cref="DbContext"/> using ASP.NET 
   ///Identity and Identity Server.
   /// </summary>
   /// <typeparam name="TUser"></typeparam>
   public class ApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser> : 
   KeyApiAuthorizationDbContext<TUser, IdentityRole, string>
   where TUser : IdentityUser
   {
       /// <summary>
       /// Initializes a new instance of <see 
       ///cref="ApiAuthorizationDbContext{TUser}"/>.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="options">The <see cref="DbContextOptions"/>.</param>
       /// <param name="operationalStoreOptions">The <see 
       ///cref="IOptions{OperationalStoreOptions}"/>.</param>
       public ApiAuthorizationDbContext(
       DbContextOptions options,
       IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions)
       : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
2. Change DbContext

   ```
   public class ApplicationDbContext : KeyApiAuthorizationDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, 
   int>
   {
       public ApplicationDbContext(
           DbContextOptions options,
           IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, 
           operationalStoreOptions)
       {
       }
       public DbSet<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Finally, change startup.cs

   ```
   services.AddIdentityServer()                
       .AddApiAuthorization<AppUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
   ```